# Find xpath or something similar (=identifier) on web page

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to click on a place on a video. I tried it with xpath already, but without success.

For example on this tiktok video: https://www.tiktok.com/@willsmith/video/7125844820328926510?is_from_webapp=v1&item_id=7125844820328926510&web_id=7139992072584676869

I'm trying to click on the heart with selenium (python).
That's my code:

```
    if driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/button[1]/span/div/svg/g/path") :
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/button[1]/span/div/svg/g/path").click()
```

It says that it's "Unable to locate element". I don't know why. I even added some sleep to the code because I thought that the website didn't load up fully or even tried with a different xpath.
I also tried to do it with the ID of the "heart-location" but the ID is very hard to understand if I inspect element.
Could someone please help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you might need to login access to react on a video!

Comment: running `$x("//span[@data-e2e='like-icon']/..")` in the console seems to work ... but not your xpath ...maybe better to use `//span[@data-e2e='like-icon']/parent::button`

Comment: @XO56 Sorry, forgot to mention that I'm already logged in.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Isn't "$x" a Java code?

Comment: no $x will run xpath in your browser console

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. You need to use the correct locator
2. And to wait for the element to be clickable.
   For the former `WebDriverWait` Expected Conditions explicit wait should be used.
   The below code works:
   (In case you are already logged in)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
url = "https://www.tiktok.com/@willsmith/video/7125844820328926510?is_from_webapp=v1&item_id=7125844820328926510&web_id=7139992072584676869"

driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-e2e='like-icon']"))).click()
```

In case you want to use XPath instead of CSS Selector just change the line above with

```py
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@data-e2e='like-icon']"))).click()
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!
I didn't know that such a thing as "wait.until" has existed, and the function "By.CSS_SELECTOR" was apparently the solution here!

Comment: This is a very useful tool Selenium uses. You almost always need to wait for element to be ready for clicking (clickable) or visible for read their texts etc. Read about it! Here https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/ and here https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html you will find some documentations

Comment: There are also waits for element presence and much more